# How to create a full width triangle at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want just to do that:

[image: flag]

However I have a lot of troubles to do it with css... Someone can help me?

This is my better try:

```css
.flag.vertical {
    background-color: #dd7758;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag-wrapper"><span class="flag vertical">-5%</span></div>
```

My doubts are about to make this white triangle on the bottom. Doesn't matter here the vertical align of the text and the font family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea with gradient where it will be responsive and you will have better support than clip path:

```css
.flag-wrapper {
    background-color: #dd7758;
    padding:10px 5px 30px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    background:
      linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 48%,#dd7758 50%) bottom left/50% 15px,
      linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 48%,#dd7758 50%) bottom right/50% 15px,
      linear-gradient(#dd7758,#dd7758)top/100% calc(100% - 15px);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag-wrapper">-5%</div>
<div class="flag-wrapper">-25%</div>
<div class="flag-wrapper">-100%</div>
```

You can also make it working with image as background but you lose transparency:

```css
.flag-wrapper {
    background-color: #dd7758;
    padding:10px 5px 30px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    background:
      linear-gradient(to bottom right,transparent 48%,#ccc 50%) bottom left/50.1% 15px,
      linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 48%,#ccc 50%) bottom right/50.1% 15px,
     url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1069)center/cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag-wrapper">-5%</div>
<div class="flag-wrapper">-25%</div>
<div class="flag-wrapper">-100%</div>
```

Comment: Wow! It's interesting. Yep, everything is solved with this solution! :D Browser support, responsiveness, transparency... Amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AralRoca added another way in case you want to deal with images, but without transparency

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. Is very useful!

Answer (score 5):

Set the `width` to `0`

```css
.flag-wrapper{ background-color: #dd7758;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
   text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
    width: 0; 
    }

span{
margin-left:-10px
}
```

```html
<div class="flag-wrapper"><span>-5%</span></div>
```

Comment: This is very useful, thank you! :) Another question that maybe do you know. If I want to add this div over a image, is it possible that the triangle will be transparent instead of white?

Comment: Your solution is useful for just this use case. However, my idea is that the text that is inside can be whatever. And the size of the container is fixed and is not adapting depending the text inside :(

Comment: If the size of the container is fixed and you enter large text, it will get truncated

Answer (score 3):

You can user after element for a triangle

**Edit:** You can use  `clip-path` to make a shape as you want
This also solves your `Another question that maybe do you know. If I want to add this div over an image, is it possible that the triangle will be transparent instead of white?` comment

```css
.flag.vertical {
    background-color: #dd7758;
    padding: 10px 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 50% 70%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flag-wrapper"><span class="flag vertical">-5%</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code, you'll also be able to add enough content in your `div`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flag {
  width: 110px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative; 
  background: hotpink;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.flag:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid white;
  border-left: 55px solid transparent;
  border-right: 55px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag">
  5 Items
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may hide bottom triangle with another div

HTML:

```
<div class="flag-wrapper">
   -5%
   <div class="pointer">
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.flag-wrapper{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: #dd7758;
  width:50px;
  height:65px;
}
.pointer{
  content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 54.5px;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    transform: rotate(45deg) skew(5deg, 5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(5deg, 5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(5deg, 5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(5deg, 5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(5deg, 5deg);
}
```